# How to find PST files on remote computers using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting

I need some help. I cant’t find what’s wrong with my PowerShell script.

The goal is quite simple. I have to find (.*pst)-files on the users profile on domain computers in the network. 
Location to search is “C:\Users\”.
List of the PC names where exported to listcomputer.txt. 
The trouble is the script run with **no errors** and **no message** at all.

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\temp\listcomputer.txt
$filePath = "C:\Users\" 
foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) 
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock 
{Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst, *.ost'} }}
```

First of all I’ve to check connectivity to hosts by `Test-Connection` cmdlet.

Separately each of the command run successfully. I've tried it.

For example: `Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer`
runs with “true” result and it’s OK.

Also
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst'}` 
The result is displayed data with information about files were find in folders.

But all together run with no visible result in the PowerShell console
 [console view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACAxX.jpg)

Regards!

Comment: Try to add `$a = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatisticsSummary
return $a` at the end of your ScriptBlock and let me know the result.

Comment: `$filePath` is unknown in the scriptblock. Try `Get-ChildItem -Path $using:filePath ..` or hardcode the `'C:\Users'` there. You can also define it as param(..) in the scriptblock and use `ArgumentList` in Invoke-Command

Comment: You can read about what Theo mentioned in above comment in [about_remote_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1) and [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1):

`.pst` can be located anywhere, even other drives, or attached storage. You are only looking for `C:\`.

So maybe this refactor to hit all potential connected drives.:

```
Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\listcomputer.txt' | 
ForEach-Object { 
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $PSItem -Quiet)
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem -ScriptBlock {
            (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk).DeviceID | 
            ForEach-Object {
                If ($PSItem -eq 'C:')
                {Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSItem\Users" -Recurse -Include '*.pst, *.ost'}
                Else {Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem -Recurse -Include '*.pst, *.ost'}
            }
        } 
    }
}
```